# transparency issue when importing from illustrator into photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator, transparency

I have a document in Illustrator, entirely comprised of vector elements that I want to bring into Photoshop to edit.

The top most object is a gradient with transparency and this entire gradient disappears when I import the file into Photoshop, everything else in the document including other gradients with transparency appear as they should.

Why is this occurring and how can I solve my issue?

Comment: what kinds of documents are you using? Is the gradient an Illustrator-made object or did you place it in Illustrator?

Comment: Oops sorry should have mentioned, entirely vector. Some gradients and blending modes applied.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn't explain why it's occurring but the following two workarounds helped to some degree, but neither are ideal:

• Save .ai as an EPS (although then there was white outlines around things like a low resolution/transparency flattening type effect)

• Save .ai as a high resolution JPEG